# Visual Studio 2015 and 2013 debugger not working after page refresh

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I'm not sure what has changed but I can't debug a web site with VS 2013 or 2015 without issues. I can debug a site with 2010.

**Here's what is happening:**
I build the site and click debug. I set a break point on page 1, and a break point on page 2. The break point on page 1 will be hit, but when I navigate to page 2 Visual Studio stops debugging but the browser stays open. This also happens if I have a two break points on page 1. For example if I have a break point in the 'page load' it will be hit, but once the page is refreshed from a button click / other any other break points will not be hit and Visual studio quits debugging but the browser stays open.

**Here's what I've tried:**
1. reset the Visual Studio settings
2. Disable the "Just My Code" option in the Debug/General settings
3. checked "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" and "Use Native Compatibility Mode"
4. cleared all dot net temp files
5. delete the .suo files and user files
6. cleaned the project 
7. rebuilt the project
8. updated Visual Studio

What could be causing this issue? The only other thing I could think of is that there is a setting / other in the browser that is causing the disconnect - but if so what and why would it work in vs2010? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Same thing is happening to me.